Should we modify this snippet describing Chinese.SE for the purpose of celebrating our 10-year anniversary?
As Chinese.SE approaches/passes the 10 year milestone, part of the celebration is adding a snippet to a Stack Exchange Blog post.  Currently it will say:

A site for experts, language enthusiasts and people who have interest in the Chinese language. Whether you're a native speaker or not, this is the place for you. This site is about discussing about the finer points of the language, but also about less expert questions that might be encountered both when learning the language itself or when you're just interested in how it works.
– Most Upvoted Question / Most Popular Tag: translation

We have a chance to modify this (if we wish to do so).
Honestly, I have no idea who wrote this, but it's not bad in my opinion (so I would be okay with it unmodified).  However, I'd be tempted to highlight Chinese dialects, and there are some points in this snippet which feel a bit like "fluff".  But still, the overall point comes across.
Question: Should we modify this snippet describing Chinese.SE for the purpose of celebrating our 10-year anniversary?

Maybe nobody actually wrote it. You never know these days - it could have just been generated using an algorithm fed using the site's contents, then briefly checked over by a member of SE staff for obvious errors.

Looks like it's mostly straight from: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
